# what do these symbols mean as part of the parameters ?. and ?:

Tags: javascript, typescript

Would be great if there is a place we can look up the meaning behind these symbols. Anyway I try to understand these codes, but I don't know how to read it because I am not sure what are these symbols mean, ?: and ?.

Two occassions they are used;

```
1) case

<custom-tag [count]="totalDisplay?.sum" [params]="someConditions"></custom-tag>

2) case

export class Filter implements PipeTransform {
 transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
   return value+1;
 }
}
```

Comment: those simply means these are optional arguments

Comment: @A.T. thanks for answering this post. I have never seen these syntax before, maybe there are more that I have seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case 1**

`?.` symbol in the template is the `safe` operator.

`totalDisplay.sum` - in this case, if `totalDisplay` is undefined or null (later *falsy*), exception will be thrown because we want to access a property of a falsy object. So using `totalDisplay?.sum` with `?` operator we told that if `totalDisplay` is falsy, don't access it's property and just return `null`, otherwise access the property `sum` and return the value.

**Case 2**

`?` symbol in the function parameters means that the parameter is optional, you can pass it or omit it. Compiler will not argue for the not passed parameter. If not passed, it will be `undefined`.